# Get the last element of each entry in a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

I have a map and I want to extract the last value for each key from that map, but I can't get it:

```java
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class MyTestClass {

    private static final String almacenNombreClase = "Professor";

    private static final String TXT = "TXT";
    private static final String NUM = "NUM";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapNombreClaseYPropiedades = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.put("Professor", Map.of("texto", TXT, 
                                                            "tipo", TXT, 
                                                            "prueba", NUM, 
                                                            "dificultad", NUM ));
        mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.put("Exam", Map.of("texto", TXT,
                                                      "nivel", NUM ));

        //values of mapNombreClaseYPropiedades
        Map<String, String> valores = mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.get(almacenNombreClase);

        valores.forEach((k, v) -> {
            // Here I want to check the last element of each entry
            if (v instanceof String ) {
                System.out.println("String " + k + ",");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Integer " + k + ",");
            }
        });
        // I want to see output
        "dificultad=NUM"
        "nivel=NUM"
    }
}
```

Extract:

```
dificultad=NUM
nivel=NUM
```

i.e. the last NUM entries for each key

Comment: Are `texto`, `tipo`, `prueba`, `dificultad` and `nivel` fixed? i.e. Do you know all of them in advance? Or are they completely dynamic? i.e. they can be anything

Comment: Can be dinamic or anything @fps

Comment: The accepted answer technically works with your code due to the fact that the underlying implementation of Map.of() is order preserving (not guaranteed by the interface). But if this is a school assignment I would attempt to work through the problem using standard the Map interface. The way you've written it tells me you do not understand the data structures involved well.

Comment: yeah I was going to say the accepted solution has an error. Your output demonstrates you want the last entered `NUM` in the fields map. However, a map is unordered and so the results change each time the solution is executed. The solution could be adapted using String -> List<String> to define the mapping between Prof -> List of fields, then have a map that maps String -> datatype (String/Class). The accepted solution can then be adapted to work nicely.

Comment: How can you get the last value in something that is defined in `Map.of()`?  The k/v entries may not be in the same order as they appear in the `Map.of()` initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to extract the last value from `Map<String,String>` and then collect them using [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) into `LinkedHashMap` to save the insertion order

But as a note to preserve the order you have to use `LinkedHashMap` for input and output as well

```
    Map<String,String> valores = mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.values()
            .stream()
            .map(map->map.entrySet().stream().reduce((prev,next)->next))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue, (prev,next)->next,LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapNombreClaseYPropiedades = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.put("Professor", new LinkedHashMap<>() {{
        put("texto", "TXT");
        put("tipo", "TXT");
        put("prueba", "NUM");
        put("dificultad", "NUM");
    }});
    mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.put("Exam", new LinkedHashMap<>() {{
        put("texto", "TXT");
        put("nivel", "NUM");
    }});

    mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.values().stream()
            .map(lhm -> lhm.entrySet().stream()
                    .skip(lhm.size() - 1)
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(last -> last.getKey() + "," + last.getValue()))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is a solution that will ensure the order of the map, and it shows that you can skip, rather than reduce, since that's really what you're doing when you want the last element.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do the following as a simple stream won't work because the inner maps are not ordered and thus may give inconsistent results.

- first, the  inner map needs to be a `LinkedHashMap`.  This guarantees the order will not change from one run to the next.
- write a utility method that takes the keys just like `Map.of()` but returns a LinkedHashMap.

Now create the map

```
private static final String TXT = "TXT";
private static final String NUM = "NUM";

Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapNombreClaseYPropiedades =
            new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.put("Professor", createMap(
            "texto", TXT, "tipo", TXT,
                    "prueba", NUM, "dificultad", NUM));
    
mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.put("Exam", createMap(
            "texto", TXT, "nivel", NUM));
```

Now simply stream the values and create a List of the entry sets. This works by pulling off the last entry in the created list.  The `entrySet` is  guaranteed to maintain the order because it is a  linked list. Null and empty maps are filtered out.

```
List<Entry<String,String>> last = mapNombreClaseYPropiedades.values()
            .stream().filter(s->s != null && !s.isEmpty())
            .map(m -> new ArrayList<>(m.entrySet()))
            .map(lst -> lst.get(lst.size() - 1))
            .toList(); // java 16 - or use .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
System.out.println(last);
```

Prints

```
[dificultad=NUM, nivel=NUM]
```

Here is the method that returns a `LinkedHashMap`

```
    
private static Map<String,String> createMap(String...keyValues) {
    Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < keyValues.length; i+=2) {
        map.put(keyValues[i], keyValues[i+1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```